# jQuery cdn giving wrong magic number jquery.css file

Tags: jquery, gzip, cdn, azure-application-insights

We have some availability test for our website, which includes the css file

> https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css

The test tool (Azure Application Insights) is now for this file giving the error

> The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.

When opening the file in a browser, it works, atleast without Chrome Developer Tools complaining.

Comment: I'm also getting this from Azure Application Insights, not sure also what is going on
 Exception (subtype 'InvalidDataException') occured at 08/23/2018 16:57:55 (UTC) for Uri 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js', step #1 with the error 'The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.', exception text 'System.IO.InvalidDataException: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.

Comment: this could be anything related to the file compressed sent by https://code.jquery.com ??

Answer (score 2):

We also have the same issue with https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js file from yesterday. it was started giving issue with West US first and now its giving errors for all regions but Application is working fine.

We reached out to Microsoft and they suggested that un-check the "parse dependent request" check box in Availability test for temporary fix.

Comment: thanks, just did that and see if i just stop receiving all those emails about this

Answer (score 1):

We just changed https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js and this stopped the issues

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same issue with https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js.
Not all regions are affected, some gives 100% availability.
I tested the page using https://www.site24x7.com/web-page-analyzer.html and obtained success for different zones. Also the issue with jquery.js wan't reproduced in VMs created in different zones.

MS Support filed the ticket https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4162
which caused https://github.com/jquery/codeorigin.jquery.com/issues/43 which seems to be fixed.

Availability tests work just fine in Azure.